# Laravel Eloquent Save Item

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I try to save an item in Laravel it says the following.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

I have followed the documentation, and i can delete items fine just not update. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
 public function publishedMain($id, $state){


    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $userAdmin = Auth::user()->admin;


    if($userAdmin == "0"){
        $clients = Clients::whereRaw('id = ? and parent = ?', array($id, $state));
        $clients->active = $state;
        $clients->save();
        die('not admin');
    }else{
        $clients = Clients::whereRaw('id = ?', array($id));
        $clients->active = $state;
        $clients->save();
        die('admin');
    }
}
```

Many Thanks
Brent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `save()` method on the query builder, not on your model.

You're missing the `->first()` piece:

```
$clients = Clients::whereRaw('id = ? and parent = ?', array($id, $state))->first();
```

Of course, this will get the first client, so naming the variable `$clients` makes not much sense.

You shall also check if your `$clients` variable is not null, in which case it didn't find anything.

(btw, your model should be called `Client`, not `Clients`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't understand how I'm meant to update the item? I just want to change one value?  I can fetch data, delete it all fine inside of my controller but not update?

Comment: whereRaw() just adds a condition, it does not fetch anything.

Comment: I have added my get, but still when I save it says

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save()

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant `->first()`. Try it. | `->get()` gets all that match, so you got a collection of the rows.

Comment: Keep in mind this will only update the first returned result.  If you have a bunch of clients you need to update, you will need to loop through them and save them as you go.

Comment: @user3158900 true, but since the query is by id, it's not gonna return more than one anyway.

Comment: Understood, I just figured if that was the case, he wouldn't also need to query for `parent` so thought it deserved mentioning.